# Send selected item spinner to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner, android-spinner

I'm trying to make booking activity with spinner, i have created spinner which is receiving data from json url and it's working perfectly, but now i want to send selected item from spinner to database. What code i have to use ?

This is my actual code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String jsonURL = "https://jsonfile.php";
    private final int jsoncode = 1;
    private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ArrayList<ModelData> modelDataArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spCompany);

        loadJSON();

    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private void loadJSON(){

        showSimpleProgressDialog(this, "Loading...","Fetching Json",false);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(jsonURL);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response=e.getMessage();
                }
                return response;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //do something with response
                Log.d("newwwss",result);
                onTaskCompleted(result,jsoncode);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void onTaskCompleted(String response, int serviceCode) {
        Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
        switch (serviceCode) {
            case jsoncode:

                if (isSuccess(response)) {
                    removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog

                    modelDataArrayList = parseInfo(response);
                    // Application of the Array to the Spinner

                    for (int i = 0; i < modelDataArrayList.size(); i++){
                         names.add(modelDataArrayList.get(i).getName().toString());
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getErrorCode(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ModelData> parseInfo(String response) {
        ArrayList<ModelData> tennisModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("true")) {

                JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                    ModelData playersModel = new ModelData();
                    JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    playersModel.setName(dataobj.getString("name"));
                    playersModel.setCountry(dataobj.getString("country"));
                    playersModel.setCity(dataobj.getString("city"));
                    playersModel.setImgURL(dataobj.getString("imgURL"));
                    tennisModelArrayList.add(playersModel);

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tennisModelArrayList;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess(String response) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.optString("status").equals("true")) {
                return true;
            } else {

                return false;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getErrorCode(String response) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            return jsonObject.getString("message");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "No data";
    }

    public static void removeSimpleProgressDialog() {
        try {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    mProgressDialog = null;
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();

        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            re.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void showSimpleProgressDialog(Context context, String title,
                                                String msg, boolean isCancelable) {
        try {
            if (mProgressDialog == null) {
                mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, msg);
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);
            }

            if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            re.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now i have perfect output but i want to add button which will send selected item from spinner to firebase.

Comment: add spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener in your onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
spinner = findViewById(R.id.spCompany);
```

Add this:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
    id) 
    {              
        ModelData selectedModelData = modelDataArrayList.get(position); 
        // After that you can send this object anywhere you want to use
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay I added this now what to add for button to send selected item from spinner to my firebase?